# Como melhorar esta função de "flattening" duma lista

Tags: python-3.x, recursão

Na escola estamos a estudar a recursividade, mas claro que essa nunca é obvia. Temos que criar uma função que "flatten" a lista. Já tive a ver alguma coisa na net, e resolvi a minha nesta maneira:

```python
flattened_list = []

def flatten_list(ls=[]):
    global flattened_list

    for elem in ls:
        if not isinstance(elem, list):
            print("ADDING NO-LIST ELEMENT...")
            flattened_list.append(elem)
        else:
            print("RECURSION...")
            flatten_list(elem)
```

O problem é que a `flattened_list` é uma lista global, que se tem que chamar exatamente assim, para que a função funcione. Posso melhorar este aspeto?

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção é criar uma função aninhada:

```python
def flatten_list(ls=[]):
    flattened_list = []

    def aux(ls):
        for elem in ls:
            if not isinstance(elem, list):
                print("ADDING NO-LIST ELEMENT...")
                flattened_list.append(elem)
            else:
                print("RECURSION...")
                aux(elem)

    aux(ls)

    return flattened_list
```

#### [Exemplo funcional](http://ideone.com/tArs2R)

---

Veja porém que existem maneiras mais eficientes e genéricas de implementar essa função.

Algumas sugestões:

- [SOen: Flattening a shallow list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)
- [SOen: What is the fastest way to flatten arbitrarily nested lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823877/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-flatten-arbitrarily-nested-lists-in-python0)
- [SOen: Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: Pode sim. Esse é um exemplo de uma *closure*. A função `aux` enxerga a `flattened_list` instanciada no corpo da função `flatten_list` (i.e., `aux` "se fecha" sobre o escopo da função `flatten_list`), ou seja, cada chamada a `flatten_list` cria e retorna uma lista independente.

Answer (score 1):

Já descobri. Basta passar a lista como parâmetro e quando chamo a função no passo recursivo passo-a sem problemas e sem modifica-la, justo?

```
flattened_list = []

def flatten_list(ls=[], flattened_list=[]):
    for elem in ls:
        if not isinstance(elem, list):
            print("ADDING NO-LIST ELEMENT...")
            flattened_list.append(elem)
        else: # elem is a list
            print("RECURSION...")
            flatten_list(elem, flattened_list) # passando a 'flattened_list' sem problemas
    return flattened_list
#

ls=[12, ["MANO,", "OLA", [12, "COMO", ["ESTAS", ["?", ["?"]]]]], 14, [20]]

# TESTES
print(flatten_list(ls, flattened_list))
print(flattened_list)
print(len(flattened_list))
```

Comment: Cuidado, usar uma lista como argumento padrão de uma função pode causar surpresas! Se você alterar a lista em uma chamada da função, essa alteração será mantida para as chamadas subsequentes. Isso quer dizer que a sua função flatten_list funciona perfeitamente bem a primeira vez que ela é chamada, mas na segunda vez você terá como resultado o valor da primeira anexado ao retorno esperado da segunda.